# É possível colocar um <v-calendar /> dentro de um <v-select />?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, framework

Por alguns motivos de padronização me solicitaram que se possível fosse colocado o 'v-calendar' dentro do 'v-select'; Pesquisei bastante e tentei de várias formas possíveis porém sem sucesso. Eu sei que isso nem é o ideal mas como foi solicitado gostaria de saber se alguém tem alguma ideia ou sabe se é possível..

```
<v-select>
 <v-calendar />
</v-select>
```

algumas tentativas

```
<v-select>
 <ComponentCalendar />
</v-select>
```

Obrigada.

Comment: Um calendário dentro de um select não me faz sentido em termos de UI, mas posso não ter compreendido a ideia. Tens alguma imagem de como deve ficar no UI?

Comment: Eu concordo que não faz o menor sentido também zz Mas sabe como é né? Pediram... É porque já existe toda uma estilização e padrão dentro do select incluindo as setas que giram e bla bla por isso essa preferência.. 
https://pbs.twimg.com/media/EX_79r6XkAgIdp7?format=png&name=small 

E vão ter outros campos que serão select, por isso a importância de 'serem iguais' e  meio que evitaria ter que fazer isso na mão e aplicar pra todos os campos que hoje já estão com o v-select

Comment: Essa imagem para mim é uma div com o icon a fazer 180 graus de rotação para mostrar que está e o v-calendar "por baixo". Podes mostrar como seria fechado? e à volta há conteúdo que se mexe quando o calendar aparece?